# how to bypass idm downloading pdf from get request

Tags: javascript, express, axios, idm

im sending a get request to server to get a pdf and open that pdf in new tab , but idm interrupt my request and download it, it change server response status to 204 and remove the headers, how to prevent idm from doing this ?

Comment: you should read idm document, this has nothing to do with javascript, express  or axios

Answer (score 0):

IDM use `content-desposition` response header to detect file and download it,
you can remove this header from server response.